# How to use the Signal / Listener classes in Ashley

Tags: libgdx

The LibGdx Ashley system includes a package `signals` that contains a class `Signal` and an interface `Listener`.  The documentation is pretty unclear on when/why/how to actually use these.
According to the documentation, [`Signal`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ashley/docs/com/badlogic/ashley/signals/Signal.html) is used to

> ...dispatch an event to multiple listeners

and [`Listener`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ashley/docs/com/badlogic/ashley/signals/Listener.html) is

> ...used to listen to a Signal.

There isn't any information other than that.  Does anyone know how these are actually used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never worked with ashley but I guess it is just a observer pattern. You create a `Signal` and `.add` objects that implement `Listener` to it. Whenever you `signal.dispatch(myObject)` all these listeners added to that signal will trigger `receive(Signal<T> signal, T object)`. Here you have access to the signal and the object you sent with it.

You use the observer pattern when you have a one to many relationship. A example could be a steering wheel with wheels. Your wheels implement the listener and the steering wheel has a signal. Whenever you turn the steering wheel you "dispatch" a signal to the wheels to notify them to turn.

If you do not understand the observer pattern I suggest you learn this first. Start by [reading this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm) and create some basic implementations of this pattern till you understand it.

[Here is a test that shows exactly how to use `Signal`](https://github.com/libgdx/ashley/blob/master/ashley/tests/com/badlogic/ashley/signals/SignalTests.java)

Comment: That 2nd link is broken

Comment: @Caketray fixed, double http somehow